# Black screen shown instead of rectangles

Tags: python, pygame, screen, display, rectangles

I am trying to a blue window that is mostly made up of rectangles, which can be turned green when clicked by the mouse, but when I run the code all that I get is a black window, and I don't know why it happens. This is my code.

```
import pygame, sys
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Worldbuilder")
global screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
global click
click = False
class tile:
    def __init__(self,x,y,tilesize):
        global a
        a = pygame.Rect(x,y,tilesize,tilesize)
    def draw(self,type):
        mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if a.collidepoint((mx,my)):
            if click:
                if type == 0:
                    type = 1
                else:
                    type = 0
        if type == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,255),a)
        if type == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),a)
global tilex, tiley
tilex = 0
tiley = 0
list = []
for i in range(1,12):
    for i in range(1,12):
        list.append(tile(tilex,tiley,50))
        tilex += 50
    tiley += 50
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                click = True
    for i in list:
        i.draw(0)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: `for i in range(1,12):`  `for i in range(1,12):`: don't put ***i*** in the inner loop. also don't name your variable *list*.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). `a` needs to be an attribute of the class `tile` instead of a global variable:

```py
class tile:
    def __init__(self,x,y,tilesize):
        self.a = pygame.Rect(x,y,tilesize,tilesize)
    # [...]
```

There are multiple problems when you generate the grid of tiles. This can be done much easier:

```py
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
        list.append(tile(i*50,j*50,50))
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame, sys
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Worldbuilder")
global screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
global click
click = False
class tile:
    def __init__(self,x,y,tilesize):
        self.a = pygame.Rect(x,y,tilesize,tilesize)
    def draw(self,type):
        mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.a.collidepoint((mx,my)):
            if click:
                if type == 0:
                    type = 1
                else:
                    type = 0
        if type == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,255),self.a)
        if type == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),self.a)

tilex = 0
tiley = 0
list = []
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
        list.append(tile(i*50,j*50,50))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                click = True
    for i in list:
        i.draw(0)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```